# ViewSwitcher vs ImageSwitcher Android

Tags: android, performance, android-animation, viewswitcher, imageswitcher

I need to display different images(in the same place on the screen)on some event, they should have a smooth transition. For the transition, I am using animation. But, for the actual loading of a different image, I want to understand the performance difference between ViewSwitcher and ImageSwitcher. What are the pros and cons of using any of these classes? Right now, I am using ViewSwitcher to switch between 2 image views and to animate.
Thanks.